# Create dict from a string or list

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

### Background

I want to generate a hash table for a given string or given list. The hash table treat element as `key` and showup times as `value`. For instance:

```
s = 'ababcd'
s = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
dict_I_want = {'a':2,'b':2, 'c':1, 'd':1}
```

### My attempt

```
# method 1
from collections import Counter
s = 'ababcd' 
hash_table1 = Counter(s)

# method 2
s = 'ababdc' 
hash_table2 = dict()
for i in s:
    if hash_table2.get(i) == None:
        hash_table2[i] = 1
    else:
        hash_table2[i] += 1
hash_table1 == hash_table2
```

> True

Usually, I use 2 methods above. One is from standard library, but is not allowed in some code practice sites. Another is written from scratch but I think it's too long. If I use dict comprehension, I come up with 2 additional methods:

```
{i:s.count(i) for i in set(s)}
{i:s.count(i) for i in s}
```

### Question

I am wondering if there are other methods to initialize a hash table from string of list, clearly or efficiently?

### Speed comparation of my 4 methods mentioned

```
from collections import Counter
import random,string,numpy,perfplot

def from_set(s):
    return {i:s.count(i) for i in set(s)}

def from_string(s):
    return {i:s.count(i) for i in s}

def handy(s):
    hash_table2 = dict()
    for i in s:
        if hash_table2.get(i) == None:
            hash_table2[i] = 1
        else:
            hash_table2[i] += 1
    return hash_table2

def counter(s):
    return Counter(s)

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=n)),  # or simply setup=numpy.random.rand
    kernels=[from_set,from_string,handy,counter],
    labels=['set','string','handy','counter'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(17)],
    xlabel="len(string)",
    equality_check= None
    # More optional arguments with their default values:
    # title=None,
    # logx="auto",  # set to True or False to force scaling
    # logy="auto",
    # equality_check=numpy.allclose,  # set to None to disable "correctness" assertion
    # automatic_order=True,
    # colors=None,
    # target_time_per_measurement=1.0,
    # time_unit="s",  # set to one of ("auto", "s", "ms", "us", or "ns") to force plot units
    # relative_to=1,  # plot the timings relative to one of the measurements
    # flops=lambda n: 3*n,  # FLOPS plots
)
```

[image: Speed comparation of methods]

Comment: You've got 4 methods there, why do you need another one anyway?

Comment: Because I am not very familiar with python standard librarys, I think maybe there exist better methods.

Comment: Why do you think there's something better than `Counter(s)`? That's pretty direct and fast for longer strings (as you show)

Comment: In your "handy" function, you could replace `if hash_table2.get(i) == None:` with the more direct `if i not in hash_table2`, otherwise it seems fine, too.

Comment: If you know the range of characters in your string (e.g. pure ascii) you could also just use a list of integers instead of a dict or counter; might be marginally faster, but probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Also, `Counter` has some nice additional features above those of a regular `dict`, e.g. you can easily compare or add/subtract Counter objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically used *Counter* or *defaultdict* for creating frequency of occurrences.

Surprisingly found poster's method of from_set outperforms both most of the time.

*Observations*

1. from_set (labeled 'set') performs the best overall
2. Various dictionary methods are only better for smaller string lengths (i.e.
   < 100)
3. Counter method is only better for a small range of string lengths.
4. from_set is 2.3X faster than defaultdict and 1.5X faster than Counter for large strings

**Algorithms**

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

import random,string,numpy,perfplot

def from_set(s):
    " Use builtin count function for each item in set "
    return {i:s.count(i) for i in set(s)}

def counter(s):
    " Uses counter module "
    return Counter(s)

def normal_dic(s):
  " Update dictionary by checking if item in it or not "
  d = {}
  for i in s:
    if i in d:
      d[i] += 1
    else:
      d[i] = 1

  return d

def setdefault_dic(s):
  " Use setdefault to preset unknown keys "
  d = {}
  for i in s:
    d.setdefault(i, 0)
    d[i] += 1

  return d

def default_dic(s):
    " Used defaultdict from collections module "
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for i in s:
        d[i] += 1
    return d

def try_dic(s):
    " Use try/except to check if item in dictionary "
    d = {}
    for i in s:
        try:
            d[i] += 1
        except:
            d[i] = 1

    return d
```

**Test Code**

[Uses Perfplot Module](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/)

```
out = perfplot.bench(
   setup=lambda n: ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=n)),  # or simply setup=numpy.random.rand
    kernels=[from_set, counter, setdefault_dic, default_dic, try_dic],
    labels=['set', 'counter', 'setdefault', 'defaultdict', 'try_dic'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(17)],
    xlabel="len(string)",
    equality_check= None
    # More optional arguments with their default values:
    # title=None,
    # logx="auto",  # set to True or False to force scaling
    # logy="auto",
    # equality_check=numpy.allclose,  # set to None to disable "correctness" assertion
    # automatic_order=True,
    # colors=None,
    # target_time_per_measurement=1.0,
    # time_unit="s",  # set to one of ("auto", "s", "ms", "us", or "ns") to force plot units
    # relative_to=1,  # plot the timings relative to one of the measurements
    # flops=lambda n: 3*n,  # FLOPS plots
    )
out.show()
#out.save("perf.png")
out
```

**Charts**

*Absolute Values*

from_set label 'set' in the diagram.  It's easier to relative performance on the relative diagram below than this absolute diagram.

[image: Absolute Values]

*Relative Values*

from_set label 'set' in the diagram.

from_set method is the horizontal line.  All other methods including Counter and defaultdict are above it (more time consuming) for larger values.

[image: Relative Values]

**Table**

Actual times

```
       n  setdefault     try_dic  defaultdict    counter    from_set
     1.0       799.0       899.0       1299.0     6099.0     1399.0
     2.0      1099.0      1199.0       1599.0     6299.0     1699.0
     4.0      1699.0      1699.0       2199.0     6299.0     2399.0
     8.0      3199.0      3099.0       3499.0     6899.0     3699.0
    16.0      6099.0      5499.0       5899.0     7899.0     5900.0
    32.0     10899.0      9299.0       9899.0     8999.0    10299.0
    64.0     20799.0     15599.0      15999.0    11899.0    15099.0
   128.0     38499.0     25499.0      25899.0    16599.0    21899.0
   256.0     73100.0     44099.0      42700.0    26299.0    30299.0
   512.0    137999.0     77099.0      72699.0    43199.0    46699.0
  1024.0    286599.0    154500.0     144099.0    85700.0    79699.0
  2048.0    549700.0    289999.0     266799.0   157499.0   145699.0
  4096.0   1103899.0    577399.0     535499.0   309399.0   278999.0
  8192.0   2200099.0   1151500.0    1051799.0   606999.0   542499.0
 16384.0   4658199.0   2534399.0    2295300.0  1414199.0  1087799.0
 32768.0   9509200.0   5270200.0    4838000.0  3066600.0  2177200.0
 65536.0  19539500.0  10806300.0    9942100.0  6503299.0  4337599.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to use the built in counter, otherwise, you may use defualtdict which is quite similar to your second attempt

```py
from collections import defualtdict

d = defualtdict(int) # this makes every value 0 by defualt
for letter in string:
    d[letter] +=1
```